# How can labels in ggplot be animated using plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

This is my dataframe:

```
combined_gas <- data.frame(
  Date_Time = as.POSIXct(c("2023-06-14 09:59:48", "2023-06-14 09:59:51", "2023-06-14 09:59:54",
                           "2023-06-14 09:59:58", "2023-06-14 10:00:01")),
  Carbon_Dioxide_Level = round(rnorm(n = 5,  mean = 0.36, sd = 0.01),2),
  Oxygen_Level = round(rnorm(n = 5, mean = 0.04, sd = 0.005),2),
  Nitrogen_Level = round(rnorm( n = 5, mean = 0.37, sd = 0.02),2)
)
```

this is the plot for it:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = combined_gas) +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("Carbon Dioxide Level = ", Carbon_Dioxide_Level, " kg"), x = 0, y = 2.0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("Oxygen Level = ", Oxygen_Level, " kg"), x = 0, y = 1.75)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("Nitrogen Level = ", Nitrogen_Level, " kg"), x = 0, y = 1.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2))
```

I want to make the values change with time and get a result like this, for example:

[image]

How can I do this using plotly

Comment: "I want to make the values change with time and get a result like this" what do you mean with time? is this in a shiny app or html doc is this a part of a larger figure? or do you want a gif

Comment: @Mike  I meant time as my  Date_Time column in my dataframe. 
The example I shown is a gif I made using Inkscape.
 I want to create something like this in plotly. So I can use it in Shiny App.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `gganimate` package. `gifski` will also be required to render into a `.gif` image. I had to restart Rstudio after installing packages, fyi.

```
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)

p2 + transition_time(Date_Time)
```

[image]

Comment: I  have already tried it using gganimate but I want the   result to be   in 'plotly'. So I can integrate the plotly object into Shiny.

Comment: you can probably save the gif as an object and call it in your app, is there a reason you need it to be plotly